# You need to call "Get.put(dynamic())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>dynamic())"

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i get the error Unhandled Exception: "dynamic" not found. You need to call "Get.put(dynamic())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>dynamic())" when i call the authController, below is my code.

```
if (Get.find<AuthController>().isLoggedIn()) {
    //statements
  }
```

my init function

```
Future init() async {
// Core
final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Get.lazyPut(() => sharedPreferences);

Get.lazyPut(() => ApiClient(
  appBaseUrl: AppConstants.BASE_URL,
));

// Repository
 Get.lazyPut(() => AuthRepo(apiClient:Get.find(), sharedPreferences: Get.find()));

 // controller
Get.lazyPut(() => AuthController(authRepo: Get.find()));
```

}

main method

```
 void main() async{
  await di.init();
  runApp(
   child: MyApp(),
  ),
  );
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

`Getx` has this great feature which is `Get.find()`, that finds the dependency you injected, but like in your example, you have multiple dependencies, let's take `sharedPreferences` and `AuthController` and we tried to find them, so we did:

```
Get.find();
Get.find();
```

on the code above, by logic it's just the same thing, same function is called, but we want that each one will find a specific dependency, so how `Getx` manages to know exactly what you want **with code** ?

it's with objects types, you need to specify a generic `Type` for each dependency so `Getx` will search for the right dependency with that `Type`, otherwise, it will just take the default type given to it, which is the `dynamic` type and this what causes the **error**.

so in your case, instead of just typing:

```
Get.find(); // Getx: how I would know what should I return?
Get.find(); // Getx: how I would know what should I return?
```

You need to specify the dependency generic `Type`:

```
Get.find<AuthController>(); // return AuthController dependency 
Get.find<SharedPreferences>(); // return SharedPreferences dependency
```

and so on, you need to specify the generic `Type` in all of them to avoid getting exceptions like this every time.

Note:

only `Get.find()` requires setting a `Type` generic to it, `Get.put()` and `Get.lazyPut()` can be specified by `Type` also but it's fine to not set them.

Comment: You saved my day with your clear explanation, I'm so grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Get.find before Get.put.

Get.put instantiates the instance while Get.find tries to find it, so assure that the instance is created before you use Get.find.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong to find X controller that:

This was wrong:

```
_sizesTabXCtrl = Get.find()<LockerSizesWidgetXController>()
```

But I needed to find like that:

```
_sizesTabXCtrl = Get.find<LockerSizesWidgetXController>()
```

try once this, if it resolves your issue.